# Python xlsx and web scraping

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, xlsx, pygooglechart

I have an Excel file which has a list of over 400 companies and I want to print Company name and get each link of the company by web scraping in Google.com. Could you please help me with this

I don't know how to attach my excel file. But here is the screenshot:

[image]

I want to get links of each company by searching on google at the same time and create an excel file of all links.
Here is what I'm doing. But it only gets one.

Comment: What do you want to do EXACTLY?  Please elaborate.

Comment: I have an Excel file. It has over 400 companies, names, locations and stuff. I want to open the file in python and then would like to get all links of the homepage of each company.  Then save them into another excel file. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this means: 'all links of the homepage of each company'.  Since you didn't provide any sample URLs, I'll just demonstrate this with a couple of generic URLs, to illustrate the idea.

Here is one idea, below, in Python.  Is this close to what you want?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

for numb in ('1', '10'):
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://realfood.tesco.com/search.html?DietaryOption=Vegetarian")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))

    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        print(link['href'])

Result:
/recipes.html
/recipes/recipe-binder.html
/top-10s.html
/helpful-lists.html
/step-by-steps.html
/recipes/collections.html
/healthy-recipes.html
/recipes/collections/family-favourites-recipes.html
/recipes/collections/on-a-budget.html
/recipes/collections/crowd-pleasers.html
/recipes/collections.html#subcategories
/recipes/courses.html
/recipes/courses/breakfast-recipes.html
/recipes/courses/lunch-recipes.html
/recipes/courses/dinner-recipes.html
/recipes/courses/dessert-recipes.html
/recipes/courses.html#subcategories
/recipes/events.html
```

Or, here is an idea, below, using VBA.  Is this close to what you want?

```
Sub HREF_Web()

Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim output As Object

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate Range("L1")

Do
'DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set doc = IE.document
Set output = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")

i = 5

For Each link In output
    'If link.InnerHTML = "" Then
        Range("A" & i).Value2 = link
   ' End If
   i = i + 1
Next

MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

Excel sheet:

[image]